# Prime ng autocomplete virtual scroll

Tags: angular, primeng

I am having 19 thousand data to load with prime ng autocomplete but freezes the whole UI when I click on drop down icon.

Have visited to github links and forums but didnt find any answer.

Is there any way I can create virtual scroll in p autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo in [stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-ztnuvv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

All you need is latest version of primeNG, Now, primeNG is supporting `Virtual-Scrol` outof the box. ALL you need to set is two properties..

```
virtualScroll = "true"
itemSize = "10"
```

Now, You have your virtual scroll PrimeNG AutoComplete is ready to use. If you see in demo link, first dropdown is without virtual scroll, and it hangs, but second dropdown its virtual scroll and its not hanging..

```
<h5>Virtual Scroll [Length - {{this.manyRecords?.length}} ]</h5>

<p-autoComplete virtualScroll="true" itemSize="4" [(ngModel)]="manyRecords" 
  [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
  (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)" field="name" [dropdown]="true">
    <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">

       <div style="font-size:18px;">{{country.name}}</div>

    </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

Thats it.

Comment: In the demo, I see that the one with virtual scroll suggestions box has a fixed width unlike the other one where the suggestions box width is dynamic and increases to fit the largest suggestion. Is there a way to make the virtual scroll suggestion box width dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

i create a directive for this issue

```
if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
  const a = document.getElementById('p-highlighted-option')?.offsetTop;
  const b = document.getElementById('p-highlighted-option')?.offsetHeight * 4;
  if (a && b)
    document.getElementsByClassName('p-autocomplete-panel')[0].scrollTo(0, a - b);
}
if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
  const a = document.getElementById('p-highlighted-option')?.offsetTop;
  const b = document.getElementById('p-highlighted-option')?.offsetHeight;
  if (a && b)
    document.getElementsByClassName('p-autocomplete-panel')[0].scrollTo(0, a - b);
}
```